# Android custom control to display map tiles

Tags: android, android-mapview, tiles, openstreetmap

I have on my server map tiles sorted on a folder structure like OpenStreetMap (OSM) uses. I need to be able to display these tiles, zoom in/out, pan and rotate the map. I wouldn't start from the scratch to create a new control. I've seen OsmDroid but I didn't find a way to set my own non vectorized tile source.

I am open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first try to check out their source code to get an understanding of how they did it.

Here is the [link](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fosmdroid-android) to their source codes. To be more precise I think that [this](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/TilesOverlay.java) is the file you are looking for.