# Java tile map loader

Tags: java, android, loader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android custom control to display map tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793290/android-custom-control-to-display-map-tiles)

I'm new with java and I'm wondering. How would I make a tile map loader in it? Can someone point me in the right direction with tutorials or something please? Thanks!

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. That link provided me with no help what so ever. I am a NEW java developer therefor I am completely lost when it comes to a tile map loader.

Comment: Actually I think the question is a duplicate. Did you look at the code they mention in that question?

Comment: No, I'm wanting a Tile Map Loader not a slippy map loader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean you want to create a [slippy map](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_Map) application with Android. I'm not aware of any tutorials in this area.  But there are plenty of open-source projects you can learn from [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android).  Here's a simple one you can start with: [MapDroid](https://github.com/tedjp/mapdroid/tree/master/src/au/id/tedp/mapdroid).

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! Although I literally mean a Tile Map. As in something like this - http://www.mapeditor.org/